# Super + Arrow (Left/Right) Moves Windows to Secondary Display

Tags: display

In the Display Settings, I have made my primary monitor the primary. It has the activities bar. But it doesn't have the desktop icons on it as the primary.

My setup is secondary monitor on the left, primary on the right. Ubuntu is halfway treating the primary as primary. It says it's primary in the display settings. It gives me the activities bar on the primary. But it doesn't actually use it as primary. Hitting Super + Left moves my window up top.

What this means is I have to always have my secondary monitor on to reposition the windows back on the primary. If I just want to hop on real quick to do a simple task with just the primary monitor, nope, both need to be turned on.

Other threads from years ago suggest that as long as you have the activities bar on the primary, then you are good to go. That's not the case for me.

I'm on the latest Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 64-bit GNOME Version 42.2 Windowing System X11 as downloaded from the official ubuntu distro with the undisableable automatic updates in full force.

Comment: Right you are. Newest Ubuntu. There may be a reason I am on askubuntu.com

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 64-bit GNOME Version 42.2 Windowing System X11. As said, latest.

Comment: Great, so I have amended the question. Do you even know the answer or are you being a grouch for the lols?

Comment: To be clear, I went to https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop to confirm the latest advertised version. It is 22.04.1 which as I told you, I have. If you don't like that I said the LATEST for what is the public facing download page of official Ubuntu distributions, you may want to update that webpage. As of Aug 26 2022 that is the version advertised for download. "Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Download the latest LTS version of Ubuntu, for desktop PCs and laptops. LTS stands for long-term support — which means five years, until April 2027, of free security and maintenance updates, guaranteed."